# Creating a Discord Bot to play .mp3 files

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

My goal at the moment is to create a Discord Bot that can play .mp3 files for my private Discord Server. This is my code. The file test.mp3 is in the same folder as the .py file. The error message is: "NameError: name 'FFmpegPCMAudio' is not defined". I added the ffmpeg  executable in my path environment variable. Can anyone help?

```
import discord
import asyncio
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "test" in message.content:
        user = message.author
        voice_channel = user.voice.channel
        channel = None
        if voice_channel != None:
            channel = voice_channel.name
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
            player = vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio("test.mp3"), after=lambda: print('done'))
            player.start()
            while not player.is_done():
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            player.stop()
            await vc.disconnect()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Try importing it from discord `from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio`

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it from the discord library

```
 from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
```